# some one help . search not jump to search page

Tags: search

i have form search :

```
<form action="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" method="GET" role="form" class="searchform"> 
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-3">
            <input type="hidden" name="post_type" value="tourdl"> 
            <div class="item">
              <label><img src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory');?>/assets/images/search-1.png" class="img-fluid" alt="">Nơi khởi hành</label>
              <input type="search" name ="noi_kh" placeholder="<?php echo esc_attr_x( 'Search &hellip;', 'placeholder' ); ?>">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="item">
              <label><img src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory');?>/assets/images/search-2.png" class="img-fluid" alt="">Điểm đến</label>
              <input type="search" name ="den" placeholder="Nhập nơi đến ...">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="item">
              <label><img src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory');?>/assets/images/search-3.png" class="img-fluid" alt="">Ngày khởi hành</label>
             
              <div class="form-group">
                    <div class='input-group date date-book' id='datetimepicker2'>
                      <input type='search' name="ngay_kh" placeholder="Ngày / tháng / năm" class="inp_date" />
                      <span class="input-group-addon"></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div> 
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="item">
              <button type="submit" class="text-uppercase btn-search" id="searchsumit" value="<?php echo esc_attr_x( 'Search', 'submit button' ); ?>">Tìm kiếm</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
    </form>
```

and here is querry in search page

```
$post_type  = isset($_GET['post_type']) && $_GET['post_type'] ? $_GET['post_type'] : 'post';
$di     = isset($_GET['noi_kh']) && $_GET['noi_kh'] ? $_GET['noi_kh'] : '';
$den    = isset($_GET['den']) && $_GET['den'] ? $_GET['den'] : '';
$nkh = isset($_GET['ngay_kh']) && $_GET['ngay_kh'] ? $_GET['ngay_kh'] : '';
$args = array(
    'showposts'     => 10,
    'post_type'     => $post_type,
    'meta_query'    => array(
        'relation'      => 'AND',
        array(
            'key'      => 'noi_khoi_hanh',
            'value'     => $di,   
            'compare'   => 'Like'
        ),
        array(
            'key'      => 'diem_den',
            'value'     => $den,   
            'compare'   =>'Like'
        ),
         array(
            'key'       => 'ngay_khoi_hanh',
            'value'     =>  $nkh,
            'type'      => 'datetimepicker2',
            'compare'   => 'Like',   
        )
    ),
);
```

?>

have_posts() ): ?>
have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>

Answer (score 1):

You’re sending your form directly to homepage. Your form doesn’t have field with name “s” in it.

So there is now way for WordPress to guess, that it should display search results instead of homepage.

Comment: Thank you, i ll try